# Regex for git's repository

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use regex to validate git repository url. I found a few answers on stackoverflow but none of them passes my tests.

The debug is here: http://regexr.com/39qia

How can I make it passes the last four cases?

```
git@git.host.hy:group-name/project-name.git
git@git.ho-st.hy:group-name/project-name.git
http://host.xy/agroup-name/project-name.git
http://ho-st.xy/agroup-name/project-name.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain since I'm not familiar with git link syntaxes, but the following regex will additionally match the 4 next values:

```
((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w.-]+))(:(//)?)([\w.@\:/~-]+)(\.git)(/)?
                             ^                     ^^    ^
```

I have indicated the changed parts; namely:

1. Added `-` to the part after `@` because `ho-st` was not passing otherwise.
2. Moved `-` to the end of the character class because otherwise `/-~` would mean the character range `/` to `~` which matches a *lot* of characters.
3. Escaped the final dot (thanks @MatiCicero)

There are a lot of things that could be simplified from the above, but since I don't know your exact goals, I'm leaving the regex as close as possible to the one you have.

Comment: `(.git)` must be escaped to `(\.git)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
(?'protocol'git@|https?:\/\/)(?'domain'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)(\/|:)(?'group'[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/(?'project'[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.git
```

You can then extract the needed information from the matched groups.

You can test this regex on: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vZ7lO5/2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the following expression matches all of your current test-text and does not match any of your false positives provided before:

```
((((git|user)@[\w.-]+)|(git|ssh|http(s)?|file))(:(\/){0,3}))?([\w.@\:/~\-]+)(\.git)(\/)?
```

See also, [regex](http://regexr.com/39qij).

**Caveat**: Be aware, that currently input is matched with '~' and '-' appearing in places where they shouldn't.